# Can I use Time Machine to Mirror two Macs?

Tags: time-machine, recovery, mirroring

Sooo.  I have a guy retiring soon, and it looks like I get to take over his mac.  I made a critical error in updating to Catalina, and lost use of alot of the apps we use here at work.  Could I restore Mac 1 (My mac) using the Time Machine set up for Mac 2 (The retiree's mac). Thinking we could use it to get Mac 1 prepared for another trainee in a week or so.

Comment: I have not tried this, but I am guessing that it would work best to reinstall the OS on that Catalina PC and then "restore" it using the desired TM backup. And be sure you have a backup of your data too, you'll likely need that as well

Answer (score 2):

Migration Assistant can 'copy' one machine to another.  I would ask your IT department first as this can really muck up management and other things.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350